# PlatformNotSupportedException CE7

Tags: compact-framework

I have a empty project (compact framework 3.5) for pda. I add a imagelist and i add a image in the list. When i deploy the project at a CE7 device (Motorola MC32N0) i get a PlatformNotSupportedException at the line

```
this.imageList1.Images.Add(((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("resource"))));
```

The stacktrace is:

```
  at System.Globalization.CompareInfo..ctor(Int32 culture)
   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(Int32 culture)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_CompareInfo()
   at System.Collections.Comparer..ctor(CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Collections.Comparer..cctor()
   at System.OrdinalComparer.EqualsStringImpl(String x, String y)
   at System.StringComparerImpl.Equals(Object x, Object y)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.KeyEquals(Object item, Object key)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoHelper(Int32 lcid, String name, String altName)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)
   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetSortingLCID(Int32 culture)
   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo..ctor(Int32 culture)
   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(Int32 culture)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_CompareInfo()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.GetHash(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.InitHash(Object key, Int32 hashsize, UInt32& seed, UInt32& incr)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)
   at SmartDeviceProject5.Form1.InitializeComponent()
   at SmartDeviceProject5.Form1..ctor()
   at SmartDeviceProject5.Program.Main()
```

I only get this exception in CE7. Any ideas?

Comment: What format is the resource image (png, bmp, jpg, etc)?  Does the device support decompression of that file type?

Comment: Any solution to that issue? I have same on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I think MC32xx has only a "core" CE7. I had a similar problem. Have you got installed Compact Framework 3.5 properly. What does the windows\wceload.exe show you? Maybe you have to install this seperately.